# Can I export Firestore data to a local file path instead of a Cloud Storage path?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use this code to export Firestore data to a bucket folder:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://PROJECT_NAME.firebaseio.com"
});

const client = new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient({});

async function doFirestoreBackup() {
  try {
    const response = await client.exportDocuments({
      name: client.databasePath('PROJECT_NAME','(default)'),
      outputUriPrefix: 'gs://PROJECT_NAME.appspot.com/firestore-backups/2020-12-02-T-12H00/'
    });
    console.log(response);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err.msg);
  }
}
```

Can I somehow save the exported data to a local path on my PC? Instead of using a bucket folder on `outputUriPrefix`?

Here is the related doc I found, but I didn't understand if what I want is possible or not:

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/google.firestore.admin.v1.FirestoreAdmin.html#exportDocuments1

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/google.firestore.admin.v1.ExportDocumentsRequest.html

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/google.firestore.admin.v1.ExportDocumentsResponse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore documentation on [exporting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data) starts with:

> An export operation copies documents in your database to a set of files in a Cloud Storage bucket.

So it seems pretty certain that it can only export to a Cloud Storage bucket. If you want to get the exported data locally, you'll have to first run the export process and then retrieve the data from the bucket to your local system with a tool like the `gcloud` CLLI or through the Cloud Storage API.